# Is it granteed the FD_CLOSE event are only posted when there is no data buffered in socket?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

We using the [WSAEventSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx) to bind an socket with an event. And From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The FD_CLOSE network event is recorded when a close indication is
>   received for the virtual circuit corresponding to the socket. In TCP
>   terms, this means that the FD_CLOSE is recorded when the connection
>   goes into the TIME WAIT or CLOSE WAIT states. This results from the
>   remote end performing a shutdown on the send side or a closesocket.
>   **FD_CLOSE being posted after all data is read from a socket**. **An
>   application should check for remaining data upon receipt of FD_CLOSE
>   to avoid any possibility of losing data**. For more information, see the
>   section on Graceful Shutdown, Linger Options, and Socket Closure and
>   the shutdown function.

Seams the first highlight sentence means the FD_CLOSE will only been posted after all data is read from socket. But the second sentence require an application need to check if there is data in socket when received FD_CLOSE. 
Isn't it conflict? How to understand it?

Comment: I agree. The text you have quoted is self-contradictory. The only way the port can go into TIME_WAIT or CLOSE_WAIT is if all pending data has already been read.

Comment: @EJP, the TIME_WAIT or CLOSE_WAIT is an state of TCP. When Kernel received FIN, it goes to those state. Why all pending data has already been read?

Comment: Because otherwise you could *never* read the last bit of data, and you can. Infallibly. Whether you're interested in FD_CLOSE or not.

Comment: @user207421 The TIME_WAIT/CLOSE_WAIT state of the TCP connection does not necessarily mean that there is no more data in the kernel buffers that the application has not read.

Comment: @nos Self-contradictory documentation can mean anything. If you have further information, please provide a reason or a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is a lot of speculation and very little official word. My understanding is the following:

> FD_CLOSE being posted after all data is read from a socket.

Edit: My original response here appears to be false. I believe this statement to be referring to a specific type of socket closure, but there doesn't seem to be agreement on exactly what. It is expected that this should be true, but experience shows that it will not always be.

> An application should check for remaining data upon receipt of FD_CLOSE to avoid any possibility of losing data.

There may be data still available at the point your application code receives the FD_CLOSE event. In fact, reading around indicates that *new data* may become available at the socket *after* you have received the FD_CLOSE. You should check for this data in order to avoid losing it. I've seen some people implement recv loops until the recv call fails (indicating the socket is actually closed) or even restart the event loop waiting for more FD_READs. I think in the general case you can simply attempt a recv with a sufficiently large buffer and assume nothing more will arrive.